# Custom function transformer not performing as expected - sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pipeline

I'm writing a custom transformer for a [scikit-learn Pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html).  The transformer seems to work on it's own, and the `fit()` and `transform()` methods work individually, but when I include it in a pipeline, it raises an error stating:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'transform'

For reference, here is the code for my custom transformer:

```py
class feature_union(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.Xt = None
        self.PI2_categories = ['D3', 'D4', 'A6', 'A5', 'D1', 'D2', 'A8', 'B2', 'E1', 
                               'A1', 'A2', 'C1', 'C4', 'A7', 'C2', 'C3', 'A4', 'A3', 'B1']     
        
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        
        product_columns = ['Product_Info_1', 'Product_Info_3', 'Product_Info_5', 'Product_Info_6', 'Product_Info_7'] + self.PI2_categories
        product_idx = [col for col in range(X.shape[1]) if X.columns[col] in product_columns]

        personal_columns = ['Ins_Age', 'Ht', 'Wt', 'BMI']
        personal_idx = [col for col in range(X.shape[1]) if X.columns[col] in personal_columns]

        medical_hist_columns = ["Medical_History_{}".format(x) for x in range(1, 42, 1)]
        medical_hist_idx = [col for col in range(X.shape[1]) if X.columns[col] in medical_hist_columns]

        family_hist_columns = ["Family_Hist_{}".format(x) for x in range(1, 6, 1)]
        family_hist_idx = [col for col in range(X.shape[1]) if X.columns[col] in family_hist_columns]

        insured_info_columns = ["InsuredInfo_{}".format(x) for x in range(1, 8, 1)]
        insured_info_idx = [col for col in range(X.shape[1]) if X.columns[col] in insured_info_columns]

        insurance_hist_columns = ["Insurance_History_{}".format(x) for x in range(1, 10, 1)]
        insurance_hist_idx = [col for col in range(X.shape[1]) if X.columns[col] in insurance_hist_columns]

        employment_info_columns = ["Employment_Info_{}".format(x) for x in range(1, 7, 1)]
        employment_info_idx = [col for col in range(X.shape[1]) if X.columns[col] in employment_info_columns]

        medical_keyword_columns = ["Medical_Keyword_{}".format(x) for x in range(1, 49, 1)]
        medical_keyword_idx = [col for col in range(X.shape[1]) if X.columns[col] in medical_keyword_columns]

        medical_keyword_columns = ["Medical_Keyword_{}".format(x) for x in range(1, 49, 1)]
        medical_keyword_idx = [col for col in range(X.shape[1]) if X.columns[col] in medical_keyword_columns]

        get_original_features = lambda X: X
        get_product_columns  = lambda X: X[:, product_idx]
        get_personal_columns = lambda X: X[:, personal_idx]
        get_medical_hist_columns = lambda X: X[:, medical_hist_idx]
        get_family_hist_columns = lambda X: X[:, family_hist_idx]
        get_insured_info_columns = lambda X: X[:, insured_info_idx]
        get_insurance_hist_columns = lambda X: X[:, insurance_hist_idx]
        get_employment_info_columns = lambda X: X[:, employment_info_idx]
        get_medical_keyword_columns = lambda X: X[:, medical_keyword_idx]


        get_medical_and_family = lambda X: X[:, medical_keyword_idx + medical_hist_idx + family_hist_idx]


        union = FeatureUnion([
            ("original_features", FunctionTransformer(get_original_features)),

            ("product_interaction", Pipeline([('select_product', FunctionTransformer(get_product_columns)),
                                              ('product_interaction', PolynomialFeatures(2, include_bias=False, interaction_only=True))
                                            ])),

            ("personal_interaction", Pipeline([('select_personal', FunctionTransformer(get_personal_columns)),
                                              ('personal_interaction', PolynomialFeatures(4, include_bias=False, interaction_only=True))
                                            ])),

            ("medical_hist_interaction", Pipeline([('select_medical', FunctionTransformer(get_medical_hist_columns)),
                                                   ('medical_interaction', PolynomialFeatures(2, include_bias=False, interaction_only=True))
                                                 ])),

            ("family_hist_interaction", Pipeline([('select_family_hist', FunctionTransformer(get_family_hist_columns)),
                                                  ('family_hist_interaction', PolynomialFeatures(5, include_bias=False, interaction_only=True))
                                                ])),

            ("insured_info_interaction", Pipeline([('select_insured_info', FunctionTransformer(get_insured_info_columns)),
                                                   ('insured_info_interaction', PolynomialFeatures(2, include_bias=False, interaction_only=True))
                                                 ])),

            ("insurance_hist_interaction", Pipeline([('select_insurance_hist', FunctionTransformer(get_insurance_hist_columns)),
                                                   ('insurance_hist_interaction', PolynomialFeatures(2, include_bias=False, interaction_only=True))
                                                   ])),

            ("employment_info_interaction", Pipeline([('select_employment_info', FunctionTransformer(get_employment_info_columns)),
                                                    ('employment_info_interaction', PolynomialFeatures(2, include_bias=False, interaction_only=True))
                                                    ])),

            ("medical_keyword_interaction", Pipeline([('select_medical_keyword', FunctionTransformer(get_medical_keyword_columns)),
                                                    ('medical_keyword_interaction', PolynomialFeatures(2, include_bias=False, interaction_only=True))
                                                    ])),

            ])
        
        Xt = union.fit_transform(X)
        
        return self.Xt
    
    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        Xt = self.Xt
        return Xt
```

And when I use it in a pipeline like this:

```py
pipeline_feat_union = Pipeline([('preprocess', preprocess()),
                                ('feat_union', feature_union()),
                                ('classifier', GaussianNB())])
```

It raises the following error:

```py
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'transform'
```

Comment: why you are not returning anything from the fit method?

Comment: Hi, Sorry that was a mistake, please see the edit. I'm now getting a different error saying AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'transform'

Comment: Why you are doing fit_transform()? fit and fit_transform are two different things. If you do fit_transform(), then you don't need to call transform method.

Comment: I was facing the same issue, as pointed out by @Jthorpe below, the fit method should return `self`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. The GuassianNB() class doesn't have a `transform` method defined.

But you don't need to use the transform method at all if you are including your classifier in the pipeline. The only two methods that you need are the `fit` method and the `predict` method.

```
pipeline_feat_union.fit(X_train, y_train)
pipeline_feat_union.predict(X_train)
```

Answer (score 2):

When writing custom transformer for a sklearn pipeline, your `fit()` method needs to return `self` or something with a similar interface, like so:

```py
class Intercept(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        # maybe do some initialization here, if your transformer needs it

    def fit(self, X,y=None):
        # Do something here to "fit" your transformer

        return self # Always return self or something with a similar interface.

    def transform(self, X,y=None):
        # apply your transformation here

        return some_awesome_transformation(X)
```

and for reference, [this is most likely the line that is throwing the exception](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/80598905e/sklearn/base.py#L867) (which is helpful because you can see why you need to return `self` in the `fit()` method)